# Oracle: Recursively self referential join with nth level record

Tags: sql, oracle, self-referencing-table

I have self referential table like this:

```
id   |level | parent_id
----------------------
1    |1     |null
2    |1     |null
3    |2     |1
4    |2     |1
5    |2     |2
6    |3     |5
7    |3     |3
8    |4     |7
9    |4     |6
------------------------
```

I need nth level parent in result. for example 2nd level parent

```
id   |level | parent_id| second_level_parent_id
------------------------------------------------
1    |1     |null      |null
2    |1     |null      |null
3    |2     |1         |null
4    |2     |1         |null
5    |2     |2         |null
6    |3     |5         |5
7    |3     |3         |3
8    |4     |7         |3
9    |4     |6         |5
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Look at this page in docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me.

```
SELECT m.*,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS second_level_parent_id
FROM my_table m
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ROOT level =2
  CONNECT BY prior id    = parent_id;
```

thanks @Jozef Dúc